# Is there a reason for an Excel worksheet macro to become corrupted in Excel 2013 but work fine in Office 355?

Tags: excel, vba, crash

So I work for a company that's a bit slow with the times and manually requires workers to input sales data into a spreadsheet at end of day. I was tired of that so I created a separate VBA Excel program to automate it.

It has been working fine for the past two months but for seemingly no reason it seems to of corrupted the spreadsheet it was altering when I ran my program recently. Attempting to open the spreadsheet and enabling macros on the work PC causes Excel (2013) to crash. Opening other worksheets and enabling macros on them works fine though.

I tried emailing it to myself to figure out why but it opens correctly and with no issues with my version of Excel (Office 365)

I know that the corruption must of occurred either before my program ran or just after it started running because it performs a backup of the spreadsheet before altering/inputting any data and the backup is also corrupted on the work pc.

To try and simplify a hundred lines of code and 5 helper functions or so; it opens the files needed with `Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & file)` where file is just the name of the workbook to be altered; it then performs a backup and deletes backups older than 7 days.

Here's the generic backup code:

```
Private Sub deleteBackup(folderName As String)
    Dim FSO As Object

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    For Each fcount In FSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.path & folderName).Files
        If DateDiff("d", fcount.DateLastModified, Now()) > 7 Then
            Kill fcount
        End If
    Next fcount
End Sub

Private Sub backup(fileName As String)
    Dim Monthly As Workbook
    Dim dateStamp As String
    dateStamp = Format(returnDailyDate(), "dd.mm.yyyy")

    ' Check if folders exist, if they don't, create them
    If Dir(ThisWorkbook.path & BackupPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        MkDir (ThisWorkbook.path & BackupPath)
    End If

    Set Monthly = Workbooks(MonthlyPath)
    Monthly.Save

    Set FileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FileSystemObject.CopyFile ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & MonthlyPath, ThisWorkbook.path & BackupPath & fileName & dateStamp & FileExtension
End Sub
```

Is there a logical reason for why this would happen or why it wouldn't work in 2013 but does in 365?
idk if it was a random inevitable hiccup involving running out of memory or something (let's just say the works dev department isn't the greatest) or whether my program caused the corruption and could potentially do it again in the future.

Thanks for your time.

Update:
 So sending the workbook that was opened by office 365 and worked in 365; back to the work PC and it works fine now. So I assume 365 has better error correction than 2013, but I still have no idea what caused the error in the first place.